# play framework oracle sequence error

Tags: java, oracle, playframework-2.0

I am trying to get a sequence from oracle using the following code :

```
// ID field
@Column(name = "REC_ID", scale = 14)
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_TEST")
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_TEST", sequenceName="SEQ_TEST", allocationSize=1)
private long recId;
```

The sequence number is 14 digits long. The problem is that I get error on the terminal :

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4381)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getInt(NumberCommonAccessor.java:112)
>       at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getInt(OracleResultSetImpl.java:942)
>       at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.getMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:194)
>       ... 31 more

I did try to use Long, Double, BigDecimal. When changing the sequence to 10 digits it works, so I have a feeling its to do with the 64-bit, but I am running java on OSX so it is 64bit java.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Your call stack shows a call to ".getInt()", implying that for some reason it is trying to return the values as an int instead of a long.  Not sure why though.  Interesting.

Comment: I saw that and I am not sure as well why does Play think its int when I set the field as long.. I wonder if anyone knows how to force it to use Long.

Comment: Seems like there is a limit in ebean that is used by play by default, according to the code of getMoreIds in [http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.avaje/ebean/2.8.1/com/avaje/ebean/config/dbplatform/SequenceIdGenerator.java#SequenceIdGenerator.getMoreIds%28int%2Ccom.avaje.ebean.Transaction%29] it returns only int and not long. very very odd.